# Getting regional settings of current user using JSOM or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsom, sharepoint-on-prem, regional-settings

I want to fetch the **regional settings of currently logged in user** NOT the current web.

Reason being, the regional settings and language settings is pushed through user profile service (or user might modify as well). So the regional settings of the web is different than the the regional settings set from the user profile.

During my investigations, SharePoint injects `_spRegionalSettings` object on the page when we add e.g., NewsFeed webpart or when we have list view. There is `SP.DateTimeUtil.js` file that SharePoint has internally to render date time based on user's settings.

I haven't found a way to achieve similar results so far.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> [Detecting the Current User’s Regional Settings with jQuery](http://sympmarc.com/2014/08/20/detecting-the-current-users-regional-settings-with-jquery/)
>
> --- By **Marc D Anderson**

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=User";
var lcid, cultureInfo, timeZone;

$.get(url,function(data){
  $(data).find("select[name$='LCID'] option:selected").each(function(){
      lcid  = $(this).attr("value");
      cultureInfo  = $(this).text();
  });
  $(data).find("select[name$='TimeZone'] option:selected").each(function(){
    timeZone  = $(this).text();
  });

  alert(lcid + "::" + cultureInfo + "::" + timeZone);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Atish, I have tried this and this approach is good but it's based on UI and I don't want to go for this approach. Would prefer some other way, if there is one. Besides, this doesn't take into consideration Day time savings.